# Send custom form fields to paytm and get in response issue with Paytm

Tags: php, api, payment-gateway, paytm

I want to get custom form fields' values in paytm payment success response,like customer name, email, contact no, other custom values which i have set.

So to get these form values back into payment success response i am using this api, but it does not give those custom form fields values back. Please have some idea how can i achieve this:

```
<?php
    $paytmParams = array();

    $paytmParams["head"] = array(
    "txnToken" => "YOUR_TXNTOKEN"
    );

    /* prepare JSON string for request */
    $post_data = json_encode($paytmParams, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

    /* for Staging */
    $url = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/fetchPaymentOptions?mid=YOUR_MID_HERE&orderId=ORDERID_98765";

    /* for Production */
    // $url = "https://securegw.paytm.in/fetchPaymentOptions?mid=YOUR_MID_HERE&orderId=ORDERID_98765";

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json")); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Initiate transaction API screenshot from paytm developer page]

Screenshot of Initiate transaction API from Paytm developer page

Comment: No, it's not giving extendInfo object in the callback response. Please help

Answer (score -1):

You should send the parameters in the extendInfo object of Initiate transaction API. All the params which you will send in this object will be received in the callback response.